# Why is max_element not showing the largest string in vector C++?

Tags: c++

In the code below I attempt to print the largest `std::string` in a `std::vector` using `std::max_element`.

I expected the output of the code below to be:

```
Harmlessness
```

The actual output I got is:

```
This
```

**The code:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    vector <string> strlist;
    strlist.push_back("This");
    strlist.push_back("Harmless");
    strlist.push_back("Harmlessness");
    cout << *max_element(strlist.begin(), strlist.end());
    return 0;
}
```

**My question:**
Can you explain why the code produced the actual output above and not the one I expected ?

Comment: Why would it compare by string length?

Comment: By default it compares strings alphabetically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default comparator for `std::string` does an **[lexicographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) comparison** (see: [std::string comparators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp)).

The string *"This"* comes later in this order than any string starting with *"H"*.

You can use another overload of [**`std::max_element`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) that accepts an explicit comparator argument:

> template<class ForwardIt, **class Compare**> constexpr
> ForwardIt max_element( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, **Compare comp**);

If you want to compare strings by length, you can use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector <std::string> strlist;
    strlist.push_back("This");
    strlist.push_back("Harmless");
    strlist.push_back("Harmlessness");
    
    // Use an explicit comparator, in this case with a lambda:
    std::cout << *max_element(strlist.begin(), strlist.end(), 
                         [](std::string const& a, std::string const& b) {return a.length() < b.length(); });
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Harmlessness
```

**Side note:** better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).